# Unable to locate error: MyViewController class is not key value coding-compliant for the key activity

Tags: ios, internationalization, storyboard

Well known error, but strange case:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PHComposerViewController 0xb65c1e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key activity.'
```

I understand that it means some outlet is referencing to controller's property, but this property is missing. I deleted this property few commits ago as well as outlet in the storyboard. But it exists somewhere I don't know. Of cause, I tried to "clean", re-clone repo, reboot, etc...

I tried to global text search by "activity" (in storyboard xmls and everywhere in the project dir), but no result.

This problem is somehow related to internationalization support, which I added. I have 3 sets: Base, Russian, English. This problem disappears when I convert English from "strings" to "interface"...

Also, error raises when I launch over old installation (current version from AppStore). Current available version doesn't have i18 support. But this point I think is more related to my internal language.

I have a walk-around with "string" -> "interface", but of cause string is preferred way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I see this exception in relation to a `UIViewController` it has something to do with a misconfigured XIB file as you implied. Go over all outlets and make sure they are properly connected and not assigned to something that doesn't exist.

I suggest to right click on "File's owner" and see that no exclamation marks are there.

[image]

In case we're talking about a storyboard file, right click the controller instance from the list on the left, not the File's Owner:

[image]

Comment: It's storyboard. I don't see there any "File's owner". I double checked, there are no controls referencing to outlet "activity". Also, I've tryied to search directly in the storyboard xml file, nothing.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there are no XIB files in your project - only one .storyboard file.

Comment: Also, PHComposerViewController's view is defined somewhere in this storyboard - true?

Comment: There're XIB + storyboard. But PHComposerViewController's is defined in the storyboard (Base). And now I also created storyboard for English to walk-around this bug

Comment: Note, state restoration is switched off.

Comment: Restoration? What do you mean? Also, have you examined the connections in the storyboard as I've demonstrated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33650/discussion-between-victor-and-stavash)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else had this issue, do this:

1. Check outlets make sure they are all assigned and that they are properly connected to the relevant items in the viewcontroller/classes (see the @Stavash's answer on how to do this)
2. Do a clean build (cmnd+shift+k)
3. **Delete the app from your simulator (or reset the simulator). I did #1 and #2 above and still had the issue. In the end I deleted the app from the simulator and rerun it - it worked!**
4. If problem persists and you have done all 3 of the above - try removing the storyboard file from bundle resource (under Project->Build Phases), run the app and let it error out. Re-add the storyboard file and run again.